# Trouble with fullcalendar.io when I try to display more than 10 events (sometimes even less)

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I'm having trouble with the fullcalendar.io, I'm trying to show a calendar on a website and it workes fine unless the amount of events gets higher. I tried to check if the dates in the database are on some way wrong, but it seems to be fine, i can't find a possible way why 10 entries work and 100 will not be shown.

Here is the code:

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            editable: false,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
            locale: 'de',
            eventRender: function(info) {
                var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                    title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                    placement: 'top',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    container: 'body'
                });
            },
            events: {
                url: 'events.php',
                failure: function() {
                    document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                document.getElementById('loading').style.display =
                    bool ? 'block' : 'none';
            }
        });

        calendar.render();
    });

</script>
```

So whenever the SQL in the "event.php" is limited to a low number, it shows a perfect calendar to me. But when the number of event goes up the failure function is activated and it's showing me my error message, as the failure function is triggered.

Is there a way to do some research why this could happen?
I manually checked the database entries, they look all nearly the same, no troubles here. In the fullcalendar documentation it says, that there is no maximum number of entries. Even if there would be a maximum, it's very strange the sometimes more than 10 entries cause an error and sometimes 15 entries are cool.
There must be something wrong with the entries, does anyone know a way how to check them or how to get an error message out of it? maybe that helps me to continue working.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: This is events.php

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include("config.php");

$sql = "SELECT `start`, `end`, `title`, `description` FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`) >=".strtotime($mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['start']))." 
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`)<=".strtotime($mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['end']))." LIMIT 100";
$arr = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[$counter]=$row;
        $counter++;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->sqlstate);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Which error message? You mean the failure part is triggered? What happens if you navigate to `/events.php` in the browser? Have you inspected the xhr in the dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the failure part is triggered. when i navigate to events.php I only get an error message when I leave $start and $end empty (error 42000). otherwise it shows "[ ]".

Comment: Sounds like the problem is events.php; can you post it? 42000 is a syntax error in your query

Comment: `does anyone know a way how to check them`...debug your PHP. You can check the browser's Network tool to see what PHP returned in the failure case (you can view the raw response of the AJAX call). Or test it independently. If you set valid start and end dates and get an empty array, then you'll need to debug the PHP code to find out why, or if you get an error you need to get the detailed error description and work out how to fix it. Add your PHP code here and debugging info, if you need more help after that.

Comment: I will check the xhr, thanks for the tipp! Maybe i will find an error in the ajax call! I will test and let you know!

Comment: The error is in events.php. Checking the xhr is pointless if navigating directly to events.php doesn't work. My guess is you're inserting non-existing params in your query string and creating a syntax error

Comment: Thanks for your answers, ChrisG is right, the error must be in the events.php file. I added the file for your information. I already thought about special characters, can it be helpful to convert the result to make sure no special characters destroy the array? How can I convert it to make the best result?

Comment: define what characters you think are "special"? And how would they get in there? If there were some there you could check it with a suitable editor which can show hidden characters (such as Notepad++). Apart from not parameterising your query (which can cause problems), there's nothing obviously wrong with your code. Have you checked that the query actually returns any rows? In the question you said it causes an error if there are more than 10 entries, but then in the comments you said it just produces an empty array. Which is correct? And if there's an error, what exactly is the error message

Comment: I thougt about German umlaute (ä, ö, ü or ß) in the title or description.

Comment: When I set the SQL query inside the events.php to LIMIT 10 it works. the calendar is showing events and when i open the events.php it's showing an array. but when i set it to LIMIT 100 it's causing the failure function and when opening the events.php it's just a blank page. No errors, no results.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, they're perfectly valid characters in JSON and in a web page (as long as UTF-8 is enabled on the page)

Comment: `No errors, no results`...do you have PHP error reporting switched on? Or perhaps errors are logged to a file? If so, check the log file

Comment: Of course if you're testing events.php independently you must pass in equivalent start and end dates on the querystring the same as fullcalendar does...are you doing that in your test?

Comment: ok, i found the problem, i manually set the limit to the point where no data output was possible. when i set LIMIT to 25 it works, limit on 26 is a blank page. so i echo'd the $sql, copied it to the phpMyAdmin and set the limit to 26 to see the row that is causing errors. It's the first row that contains a special character (it's the ß). but in the event.php i set in the header charset=utf-8 so i'm a bit confused that i'm having trouble at this point.

Comment: Again you need to check what specific error php is throwing

Comment: $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); is the solution to my problem. setting UTF-8 in the header wasn't enough, i had to set the mysqlli to utf-8 as well.

Comment: now it's showing 1000 results whithout any trouble. Thank you very much for helping me out and trying to find a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the mysqlli query had to be set to UTF-8, it wasn't enough to use a php header to set it to utf-8.

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"],$SETTINGS["mysql_database"]);

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```